# Nested aggregations in Searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick, elasticsearch-aggregation

I index for my model colors with id and name and when using aggregations with Searchkick, I need to have in the results both id and name in one hash, not separately.

How to achieve that?

This is how it works now:

**Query**

```
2.1.3 :036 > Product.search("slipy", aggs: ['colors.id','colors.name']).aggs
```

**Results**

As you can see the id and name is in separate hash and so the relationship  is broken.

```
{"colors.name"=>{"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0, "sum_other_doc_count"=>0, "buckets"=>[{"key"=>"black", "doc_count"=>149}, {"key"=>"white", "doc_count"=>124}, {"key"=>"blue", "doc_count"=>102}, {"key"=>"red", "doc_count"=>57}, {"key"=>"yellow", "doc_count"=>35}, {"key"=>"grey", "doc_count"=>26}, {"key"=>"turquoise", "doc_count"=>18}, {"key"=>"green", "doc_count"=>17}, {"key"=>"orange", "doc_count"=>8}, {"key"=>"pink", "doc_count"=>8}, {"key"=>"purple", "doc_count"=>3}, {"key"=>"none", "doc_count"=>2}]}, "colors.id"=>{"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0, "sum_other_doc_count"=>0, "buckets"=>[{"key"=>2, "doc_count"=>149}, {"key"=>13, "doc_count"=>124}, {"key"=>3, "doc_count"=>102}, {"key"=>4, "doc_count"=>57}, {"key"=>6, "doc_count"=>35}, {"key"=>7, "doc_count"=>26}, {"key"=>10, "doc_count"=>18}, {"key"=>5, "doc_count"=>17}, {"key"=>8, "doc_count"=>8}, {"key"=>9, "doc_count"=>8}, {"key"=>11, "doc_count"=>3}, {"key"=>1, "doc_count"=>2}]}}
```

The purpose of having this is to generate various filters where I need ID for backend and name for frontend. If this is not possible with searchkick, is there any other "workaround" how to achieve this?

Thank you, Miro